# How to prevent the component from being repeated using array map() in react-native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-hooks, expo

I'm implementing a calendar in `react native` with `expo`, the problem is that when I want to bring a date from the `firebase` database to paint it in calendar, it repeats several times, here a picture

[View picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjWVm.jpg)

The code is this:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      selected: "",
      usuarios: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref("DatosCli/")
      .on("child_added", (data) => {
        var datos = data.val();
        var usuariosTemp = this.state.usuarios;
        datos.key = data.key;
        usuariosTemp.push(datos);
        this.setState({ usuarios: usuariosTemp });
      });
  }

  cargarDatos = async () => {
    var userTemp = new Array();
    var data = await firebase.database().ref("/DatosCli").once("value");

    data.forEach((child) => {
      var user = child.val();
      user.key = child.key;
      userTemp.push(user);
    });
    this.setState({ usuarios: userTemp });
  };

 

  render() {

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        {this.state.usuarios.map((usuarioTemp) => (
          <CalendarList
            markedDates={{
              [usuarioTemp.date]: {
                selected: true,
                disableTouchEvent: true,
                selectedColor: "orange",
                selectedTextColor: "red",
              },
            }}
          />
        ))}
        
      
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I know that having the `map()` outside of `CalendarList` is the reason why it repeats itself several times, how would this be solved then?

The calendar library that i use is: https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to have a list of marked dates and not a list of `CalendarList` components. Right now you are looping through the dates and create a new `CalendarList` for each of your dates. Instead you want to create an object of dates. `Map` is part of the array protoype. The prop `markedDate` seems to require an object though. For that, we need to refactor your code a bit and replace map by forEach for example to construct the object.

Let's split this problem up into two steps. First we create the object of `markedDates` by using the forEach function and after that we pass it as a prop to `CalendarList`.

```
render() {
    const markedDates = {};
    this.state.usuarios.forEach((usuarioTemp) => {
        markedDates[usuarioTemp.date] = {
            selected: true,
            disableTouchEvent: true,
            selectedColor: "orange",
            selectedTextColor: "red",
         };
    };
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <CalendarList markedDates={markedDates} />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Yes! That's right but there's no date on it. . . there's a warning coming out that says: invalid prop ´markedDates of type array supplied to Calendar, expected object.thanks for you help. @Andre

Comment: Please refresh the page. I used `map` at first in my solution before I realized that the prop requires in fact an object of dates. I updated my solution and I am now using `forEach` to fill an object with the dates from the `usuarios` array.